# Pandas set column value to 1 if other column value is NaN

Tags: pandas

I've looked everywhere tried `.loc` `.apply` and using `lambda` but I still cannot figure this out.

I have the UCI congressional vote dataset in a pandas dataframe and some votes are missing for votes 1 to 16 for each Democrat or Republican Congressperson.

So I inserted 16 columns after each vote column called `abs`.

I want each abs column to be 1 if the corresponding vote column is NaN.

None of those above methods I read on this site worked for me.

So I have this snippet below that also does not work but it might give a hint as to my current attempt using basic iterative Python syntax.

```
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(len(cvotes['v1'])):
        if cvotes['v{}'.format(i+1)][j] == np.nan:
            cvotes['abs{}'.format(i+1)][j] = 1
        else:
            cvotes['abs{}'.format(i+1)][j] = 0
```

Any suggestions?

The above currently gives me 1 for abs when the vote value is NaN or 1.

edit:

I saw the given answer so tried this with just one column

```
cols = ['v1']

for col in cols:
    cvotes = cvotes.join(cvotes[col].add_prefix('abs').isna().
                         astype(int))
```

but it's giving me an error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['v1'], dtype='object')
```

My dtypes are:

```
party     object
v1       float64
v2       float64
v3       float64
v4       float64
v5       float64
v6       float64
v7       float64
v8       float64
v9       float64
v10      float64
v11      float64
v12      float64
v13      float64
v14      float64
v15      float64
v16      float64
abs1       int64
abs2       int64
abs3       int64
abs4       int64
abs5       int64
abs6       int64
abs7       int64
abs8       int64
abs9       int64
abs10      int64
abs11      int64
abs12      int64
abs13      int64
abs14      int64
abs15      int64
abs16      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: `for c in list_vote_columns_here: cvots[f'abs{c}'] = cvots[c].isna()`

Comment: what is that `f'` in front of `abs{c}`?

Comment: that's shorthand for format, so you don't need to add `.format(c)` afterwards.

Comment: it didn't work...

Comment: it actually did work @QuangHoang, just saw the new column now.  Then I guess I can convert the True or False to an int.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us just do `join` with `add_prefix`

```
col=[c1,c2...]
s=pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist(),index=df.index)
s.columns=s.columns+1
df=df.join(s.add_prefix('abs').isna().astype(int))
```

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I tried based on your answer but it's throwing an error.

Comment: @mLstudent33 no need for loop

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear but what if I want numbered abs columns, one for each vote?

Comment: update?  I better read some documentation on joins to be able to converse with you.  I'm just taking RDBMS in uni now.